# ¿Cómo hago una función que trate distintos identificadores?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tengo implementado un sistema de comentarios que permite responder a cada uno de ellos mediante un botón que abre un formulario y procesa la respuesta con Ajax. Primero a los botones les di el mismo atributo de clase pero el problema era que al enviar la respuesta, siempre la enviaba al primer comentario (no al otro que quiero responder) ya que coge el primer elemento con esa clase. Ahora he hecho que se le asigne un id al botón en el bucle que genera estos botones, de la siguiente forma:

```
//solo muestro cómo genero el botón ya que si no es muy extenso
$i=0;
while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_object($comentarios)){
                    $i=$i+1;

                        <?php echo '<td id="comentarios"><button class="responderComent" id="responderComent'.$i.'" value="'.$mostrar->IdComentario.'"></button></td>';  ?>
}
```

De esta manera, tengo para cada comentario un botón con su identificador asignado responderComent1, responderComent2, etc. Tras hacer esto no me ha quedado más remedio de poner un límite de 5 comentarios ya que para cada botón tengo que crear su función especifica en javascript que la procese porque luego cada una de ellas tiene una vez más un ID específico:

```
$("#responderComent1").click(function(){...
         $(this).before('<form action="javascript:void(0);" class="formRespuesta><input type="text" id="resp1"/>
         <button id="enviarComent1">Enviar</button></form>);
$("#responderComent2").click(function(){...
         <input type="text" id="resp2"... 
         <button id="enviarComent2"...
...
```

Despues tengo para cada botón enviarComent...:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.enviarComent1', function(){
        var texto = $(this).parents("form").find("#resp1").val();
        var idComentario = $("#responderComent1").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "procesarRespuestasComentario.php",
            data: {texto:texto, idComentario:idComentario},
            success:function(r){
                $('#respuestas1').html(r);
            }
        });
    });
```

Lo que quería saber es si hay alguna forma de poder "comprimir" todas estas funciones en una sola que pudiera diferenciar los Id's de forma que para cada uno de ellos haga su función concreta generando el campo de texto y su botón correspondientes ya que ahora tengo que tener tantas funciones `$(#responderComentX).click` y `$(#enviarComentX).click` como comentarios tenga en la página y por ello actualmente lo limito a 5.

Comment: no veo como defines el formulario donde escribes el texto del mensaje de comentario. el bucle php solo genera un php del boton. Te pongo un ejemplo de como puedes hacerlo en la solucion, pero deberas ajustarlo a tu proposito.

Comment: Si he entendido bien, puedes asignar la misma clase a los diferentes botones, asignar un listener en base a esa clase y desde ese listener indentificar el botón que haya sido pulsado por su `id`, de ese modo controlarías todo desde una sola función. Dado que das muchas vueltas en el planteamiento, no sé si es exactamente eso lo que quieres o es otra cosa.

Comment: @Jakala básicamente en el bucle muestro cada comentario que tiene la web en una tabla y al lado el botón para responder a ese comentario concreto por eso he omitido toda la info ya que la veía poco relevante, estoy estudiando un poco la solución que me has propuesto más abajo para adaptarla y ver qué tal

Comment: @A.Cedano la verdad que mi expresión no es muy buena cuando trato de explicarme, pero sí, quiero identificar qué botón se ha pulsado, para que dependiendo del botón se coja el valor correspondiente al id del comentario ```''value=$mostrar->IdComentario"``` para saber a qué comentario me estoy refiriendo, y que al enviar el mensaje en el campo con id ```#resp``` se asigne esa respuesta al comentario en concreto. Estoy estudiando las soluciones propuestas para ver qué tal. Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar brevemente, en un párrafo, cuál es la lógica? El planteamiento es confuso y creo que el problema no es tan complejo (a veces el principal problema es no saber explicar el problema). No se entiende bien si, en base al `id` se deba buscar un dato en el servidor vía Ajax para mostrarlo o qué es lo que quieres exactamente. Reconstruir un poco la lógica ayuda en estos casos, a tí mismo a entender lo que estás haciendo y a quienes responden, a darte la mejor solución posible.

Comment: @A.Cedano si claro, espero poder explicarme bien, el funcionamiento que quiero aplicar es el siguiente:

Para cada comentario, agrego a un lado un botón para responder (```responderComent```), que al pulsarlo, muestra un form con un campo de texto (```resp```) y con un botón para aceptar esa respuesta (```enviarComent```) como se ve en el código de encima.
Tras esto, en el código ajax que controla la acción del ultimo botón que he mencionado, obtengo el id del comentario (para saber a qué comentario asociar la respuesta) y el texto correpondiente y lo proceso para mostrarlo después

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado que no indicas como se genera el formulario (el campo texto), te pongo una posible solucion, pero deberas adaptar parte para indicar ese parametro (que creo es interesante).

Puedes hacer una función en tu código, que haga la acción que te interesa, pasándole como parámetro el id:

```
function responder(id, mensaje = "")
{
    // hacer el Ajax correspondiente
}
```

Y luego hacer un evento click sobre la clase que tienes definida, que se encargue de buscar los parametros desde la referencia this (esto es, desde el boton):

```
$(".responderComment").click(function(){
    Id = $this.attr("id");
    //mensaje =  $this.attr("msj");
    responder(id);
});
```

con esto, el evento se lanzara cada vez que pulses uno de los botones de comentario. Este evento buscara el Id y el mensaje (eso tendras que configurarlo tu) y se llamara a la funcion que hace el ajax, con los parametros de ese id y ese mensaje.

Comment: ¿Qué IDE usas? Estas comillas `“`, `”` no son válidas, estas tampoco `‘`, `’`. También, yo evitaría escribir `Function` con `F` mayúscula, no es el estándar.

Comment: oh, perdon! es cosa del editor de notas del mac, que es una mierda (como el propio mac). Ahora lo corrigo, gracias

Comment: Creo que no me expresé del todo bien al construir la duda, el formulario correspondiente a responder un comentario lo genero al pulsar el botón ```responderComent```, he editado el post concretando más la acción de ```#responderComent1```, aún así, gracias por la respuesta, estoy probando e intentando hacerlo funcionar

Comment: @Jakala Funcionando correctamente! mil gracias

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que lo único que varía en cada función es el número de comentario (que usas para darles un **ID** tanto al `<button>` como al `<input>`). Por ello, en tu **PHP** podrías añadir un atributo `data` al `<td>` que refleje ese número que deseamos conseguir.

```
<?php echo '<td id="comentario' . $i . '" data-numero-comentario="' . $i . '"><button class="responderComent" id="responderComent'.$i.'" value="'.$mostrar->IdComentario.'"></button></td>';  ?>
```

Una vez tengamos eso, podemos vincular la función a los `<td>` de nuestra tabla, recuperando dentro el valor de ese atributo `data` para construir el **HTML** que necesitas.

```js
$(function () {
  $('.responderComent').click(function () {
    let numero_comentario = $(this).parent().data('numero-comentario');
    let html = '';
    
    html += '<input type="text" id="resp' + numero_comentario + '">';
    html += '<button id="enviarComent' + numero_comentario + '">Comentario ' + numero_comentario + '</button>';
    
    console.log(html);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="comentario1" data-numero-comentario="1"><button class="responderComent" id="responderComent1"   value="1">Botón1</button></td>
    <td id="comentario2" data-numero-comentario="2"><button class="responderComent" id="responderComent2"   value="2">Botón2</button></td>
    <td id="comentario3" data-numero-comentario="3"><button class="responderComent" id="responderComent3"   value="3">Botón3</button></td>
    <td id="comentario4" data-numero-comentario="4"><button class="responderComent" id="responderComent4"   value="4">Botón4</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué habría que complicarse usando esto: `data-numero-comentario` cuando son datos **redundantes, pues los tienes también en `value`**?. El hecho de que los atributos `data-` existan no significa que haya que abusar de ellos. Serían útiles si se necesitan otros datos y ya las etiquetas/atributos normales se han agotado. No es el caso aquí. Debido a eso tienes mi voto negativo.

Comment: @A.Cedano Si te fijas, el **OP** llama a `$mostrar->IdComentario` en el `value` que no sé lo que devuelve. Los números los puse yo para que se viese que el **HTML** cambia. Obviamente en caso de tener el **ID** en otro campo y que este sea el número que necesitamos, no haría falta crear el atributo personalizado.

Comment: Si he entendido bien, el problema de fondo es *escuchar* un grupo de botones de una manera simple, creo que la respuesta de @Jakala arroja luz sobre una posible solución. En cualquier caso, como ya indiqué a OP en mi comentario, la pregunta no es clara y creo que meter en el escenario los atributos `data-` lo que hace es arrojar más confusión. Por eso creo que es importante tener claro que: **no deberían usarse los atributos `data-` mientras queden otras opciones propias del elemento de la que podamos hacer uso**. Tenemos el `value`, y todavía nos quedaría el texto mismo del botón, el `td`etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano Pues yo prefiero mucho más un atributo personalizado que tener que hacer `substrings` de los **ID** para extraer el número del texto (creo que es es cuestión de gustos porque no veo en que perjudica el tenerlo o no tenerlo). Respeto tu opinión, pero sin saber ninguno de los dos lo que devuelve `$mostrar->IdComentario` no sabemos si tenemos el numero que necesito para construir el **HTML** de mi solución. Sí algo se me escapa con los atributos personalizados estaré encantado de que me lo expliques para así borrar la respuesta.

Comment: Lo que se te escapa es el tema de la **redundancia**. Los atributos `data-`  serían justificados por ejemplo si quisieras mostrar una estructura de datos: `nombre, apellidos, direccion, teléfono` etc y quieres agrupar todo en un contexto. Pero para datos sueltos, ¿por qué no agotar el `value`, y si quieres pasar otro dato, ¿por qué no usar el `text` del botón, u otro elemento del `td`? Yo no hablo de *gustos*, sino de **optimización**, de no sobrecargar el código porque *me gusta programar de este modo o de otro*. **En tu código hay redundancia**, y por eso mi comentario y mi -1.

Comment: @A.Cedano ¿Me puedes decir lo que devuelve `$mostrar->IdComentario` en el código del **OP** o seguimos jugando a adivinar? Y no considero que sobrecargar el código sea llevarte algo importante a un atributo personalizado para usarlo más cómodamente que andando teniendo que manejas substrings para sacar la información. Y lo dicho, valoro tu opinión, pero no le veo motivos de peso para hacerme cambiar la respuesta.

Comment: Mi intención no es que cambies la respuesta o no. El sitio funciona así, si no estoy de acuerdo con algo voto en contra para indicar otro punto de vista. Luego OP y futuros usuarios evaluarán lo que quieran hacer. La cuestión no es qué valor haya ahí, creo que su problema principal (si entendí bien) es simplificar la escucha de un grupo de botones y que responder con atributos `data-` no ayuda a clarificar la solución. No es que esté en contra de los atributos `data-`, como dije en otro comentario, si se tratase de expresar una estructura, no dudaría en usarlos, pero no para algo simple.

Comment: @phpMyGuel no he probado tu solución ya que la anterior me ha funcionado bien, eso sí, la he tenido en cuenta para el tema de generar el html que si que me ha servido. Muchas gracias por tu aporte